# Can the extreme heat from powder coating influence frame integrity of older bikes?

Tags: safety, paint, restoration

I just got an older frame powder coated.  The shop that I took it to doesn't specialize in bikes.  They mainly do industrial grade powder coating and perhaps a car wheel here and there, so I wouldn't consider them the most knowledgeable people when it comes to handling frames.  The frame is lugged steel.  Could the heating process influence the frame's integrity?

Comment: How hot does it get?  The first danger is that the brazing of the lugs could melt -- this would, in theory, happen before the steel itself was affected.  Brazing temps are above about 850F.

Comment: (One reference says that powder coating temps are around 390F.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 400F will not affect frame integrity.